# textarea.val() value changing but not displaying on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textarea like so,

```
<textarea id="txtaFilter" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
```

and the following script,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".selector").bind('change', function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $("#txtaFilter").val($("#txtaFilter").val() + value);
        $(this).children('option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
    });
});
```

where ".selector" is a class applied to two dropdownlists.

When I chose a value on the dropdown, it appears to do nothing, but after looking at the debugger in chrome it is changing the value just not displaying it.

Does anyone know why this is? Is there something special I'm missing about the .val() property?

---

### Problem/Solution:

I forgot that there are multiple "#txtaFilter"'s on the page when I removed the $(this).siblings("#txtaFilter"), So it was accessing the hidden one instead of the visible one. Sorry about that, guess I was wrong on the question too :/

Comment: Why are you changing the `selected` property at all?

Comment: It's for functionality of the UI, it's for creating a filter expression so they have limited choices as to Field names and Operators so it goes back to the default option that tells them what that dropdown is upon selecting something.

Comment: Ok, I understand, anyways, I tested this out and it worked fine in Chrome

Comment: It must be something else then because, like I said, it's doing the correct value but just not displaying it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `val` method:

```
$("#txtaFilter").val(function(i, oldVal){
   return oldVal + value
});
```

Comment: This still doesn't display the changes for me. It changes the actual value and I can use it but the value displayed is still blank. Could this be a problem with something else?

Comment: I don't believe so, It's multiple files and I'm not really sure how to do it in jsfiddle.

Comment: Wierd, I kinda ~made~ it work in jsfiddle by copying the pagesource and copying over the JQuery, i'm just not sure what's different.
http://jsfiddle.net/2S8FK/9/
It works here, I'm baffled.

In my project it's the JQuery is split into 2 files since the Div containing txtaFilter and the 2 dropdowns (black box) is a partial view. Nothing else is different, I don't understand what it could be.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the text of a textarea.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".selector").bind('change', function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var txtaFilter = $("#txtaFilter");
        txtaFilter.val(txtaFilter.val()+value);
        $(this).children('option:eq(0)').attr('selected', true);
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I already tried this and it does the same thing. Only reason it is append is because I never changed it back, my bad.